# How can I search in date or time range

Tags: elasticsearch, date-range

I want to create new data model for some local stores, the object will store the seasonal (opening date, closing date) and (opening time, closing time)

I need to store data like this

```
{
    "open_date": {
        "from": "19/10", // like 19/10/2017, 19/10/2018 
        "to": "29/3" // like 29/2/2018, 29/2/2019
    },
    "open_time": {
        "from": "08:00:00", 
        "to": "17:30:00" 
    }
}
```

I want to check the opening stores now (current date/time is: "2019-07-08 11:36:51")

Comment: i will suggest to combine both open_date and open_time to form a single date-time field, where you can use `{"from": "now/d", "to":"now/d"}`

Comment: I have a specific date/time, how can I look for a saved data? The range is not with me, it is in the data. Could you add a simple query for it

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
    "open_date": {
        "from": "now/d", 
        "to": "now/d"
    },
    "open_time": {
        "from": "now/s", 
        "to": "now/s" 
    }
```

Comment: I have a specific date/time, how can I look for a saved data? The range is not with me, it is in the data. Could you add a simple query for it